# Retrieve child node from parent node

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a document with html. I want to retrieve child node from the root node for that I am using following code...

That is HTML.

```
<a id="Main1" onclick="RetrieveElement(this);">Test1
<div name="Top1">
</div>
<div name="Middle1">
I'm Middle.
</div>
<div name="Bottom1">
</div>
</a>
<a id="Main2" onclick="RetrieveElement(this);">Test2
<div name="Top1">
</div>
<div name="Middle1">
I'm Middle.
</div>
<div name="Bottom1">
</div>
</a>
```

**javascript.**

```
function RetrieveElement(element){
alert(this.getElementByName("Middle1").innerHTML);
}
```

However, That is not working. I have tried finding the problem but cant solve it... Any help ?

Comment: Since id should be unique, in your example you can just use `document.getElementById("Middle1").innerHTML` as there will be no other match. Otherwise, is using jQuery an option?

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get the first child element only:

```
var element = document.getElementById('Main1').children[0];
```

If you want to get the first anchor element:

```
 var element = document.getElementById('Main1').getElementById('Middle1');
```

Answer (score 1):

`getElementById` is a method of Document, not Element. Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function RetrieveElement(element){
        window.alert(document.getElementById("Middle1").innerHTML);
    }

</script>

<a id="Main1" href="#" onclick="RetrieveElement(this);">Test1</a>
<div id="Top1">
</div>
<div id="Middle1">
    I'm Middle.
</div>
<div id="Bottom1">
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Can you use jQuery?

It would be as easy as [this](http://api.jquery.com/children/)